# How to get Parallax Effect on UIButton in tvOS?

Tags: swift, parallax, tvos

I'm trying to make some `UIButtons` in a `UIView` for a tvOS app but have been unable to get them to display the new parallax effect in the simulator. I successfully set up a TV image stack in `images.xcassets` called "startReadingButton" and my buttons load with the file, but they do not display the shiny parallax effect when swiping around on the remote in the simulator. Here is how I am loading my UIButtons:

```
   for button in 1...5 {

        let image = UIImage(named: "startReadingButton")

        let newButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        newButton.frame = buttonRects[button - 1]
        newButton.setBackgroundImage(image, forState: UIControlState.Focused)
        newButton.imageView?.image = image
        newButton.imageView?.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
        newButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered)
        newButton.tag = button
        newButton.canBecomeFocused()
        newButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = true
        newButton.clipsToBounds = false
        self.addSubview(newButton)
        self.homeButtons.append(newButton)

    }
```

So far, I have tried almost every variation I could think of to find a solution, like setting the button type to both .Custom and .System, setting the image in different parameters of the UIButton, etc. However I cannot get the buttons to enter parallax mode and move around when they are focused.

Anyone know what I need to do to get the desired parallax effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved my problem -

Set your LSR or Apple TV image stack in your `UIButton`'s `setImage` property for the `UIControlState.Focused` state.

Set the `imageView?.clipsToBounds = false` on the `UIButton`.

Set `newButton.imageView?.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true` on the `UIButton`.

I have got the following code to work as expected:

```
  for button in 1...3 {

        let buttonUnpressedTexture = UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("startReadingUnpressed.png"))!
        let buttonPressedTexture = UIImage(contentsOfFile:NSBundle.mainBundle().resourcePath!.stringByAppendingPathComponent("startReadingPressed.png"))!

        let newButton = UIButton(type: .Custom)
        newButton.frame = buttonRects[button - 1]
        newButton.setImage(buttonUnpressedTexture, forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        newButton.setImage(buttonPressedTexture, forState: UIControlState.Highlighted)
        newButton.setImage(UIImage(named: "StartReadingButton"), forState: UIControlState.Focused)
        newButton.imageView?.clipsToBounds = false
        newButton.imageView?.adjustsImageWhenAncestorFocused = true
        newButton.addTarget(self, action: "buttonPressed:", forControlEvents: UIControlEvents.PrimaryActionTriggered)
        newButton.tag = button
        newButton.canBecomeFocused()
        self.addSubview(newButton)            
    }
```

"StartReadingButton" is an Apple TV image stack in my images.xcassets catalog.

Comment: I've noticed that if I use an image stack and try using static PNGs for the other states that the effect is jumpy when moving from focused to normal. If I use the same stack for each of the 3 states presented above, it looks great.